# How can a beginner use AWS services to host a public server and create endpoints for a web application

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, web-applications

I have been in the front end development before, but this is my first time researching how to use AWS services to host a public server for our web application. Currently, I have trouble understanding how does EC2 and API gateway work with each other. And I also have some trouble understanding how does public server host a web application in this case. I have reads a number of tutorials, but I have trouble understanding where does this API endpoint generate in this case. I saw that API gateway could generate an endpoint, but in this case, do I still use EC2 to host the web application? And how can the url from these 2 connect to each other? Yeah, I think I got messy on understanding this web app structure especially on server side. Coud someone help me on breif explain on these 2 services and maybe some useful tutorial that I could reference? As a beginner, everything is so confusing to me. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple approach is deploy your web/app server in EC2 instance and check on which port yours service is running e.g. 8080 , go to attached securty group of that EC2 instance and open port for 8080, you can also attach the elastic IP so that even after restart EC2 instance your IP will never change and then access your application publically using `http;//<elastic-ip>:8080/<>`
btw best approach is to use ELB on ECS/EKS and then use API gateway deploy your static content in S3 and use cloudfront.